# Fatal PHP error when installing laravel on the server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

When I want to install my Laravel app on a webserver, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setStatusCode() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\object, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response returned in /home/yannickw/public_html/phomtec_api/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:475
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: whts laravel version you are using and whats your php version on your server?

Comment: Laravel 7 with php 7.3

Comment: Is it a fresh installation of Laravel or an existing project? What was the environment when the app worked fine?

Comment: Its was a fresh installation. Localy evertything works fine

Comment: I think there is a wrong version of php on your server, are you sure it is 7.3?

Comment: PHP 7.3.18 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 07:00:15) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.18, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.3.9, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.18, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Yes I am sure :)

Comment: That just says your CLI uses PHP 7.3. What about the webserver?